# One of two similar while loops is causing segfault at fread

Tags: arrays, c, file-io, segmentation-fault

I am trying to load two files into memory, one as an array of 2d arrays of chars (i.e., a char ***) and the other as a hash table. My whole file is below, and I can share the files in files/ if they are asked for. My goal is to implement a minimax algorithm to solve a game a friend made called WordBord ([wordbord.com](https://wordbord.com), and I decided that C would be the most efficient language. If you have suggestions for other languages (I am proficient in Python and know probably enough Java to get this done), please tell me. I am mainly doing this to challenge myself.

Program:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BOARDS 730
#define BOARD_SIZE 5
#define NUM_BUCKETS 3001

/*
 * Plan: Board layout:
 * Array of 2d arrays, so a char *** array (lol)
 * Array of strings (words)
 */

struct node {
    struct node *next;
    char *word;
};

char ***boards;
struct node **words;

// Djb2 hash function
// Code from:
// https://gist.github.com/MohamedTaha98/ccdf734f13299efb73ff0b12f7ce429f
unsigned long hash(char *str) {
        unsigned long hash = 5381;
        int c;
        while ((c = *str++))
            hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */
        return hash % NUM_BUCKETS;
}

bool isword(char *str) {
    unsigned long int idx = hash(str);
    struct node *node_ptr = words[idx];
    while (node_ptr != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp(node_ptr->word, str)) {
            return true;
        }
        node_ptr = node_ptr->next;
    }
    return false;
}

void add(char *str) {
    // Add string to hash table
    printf("%s\n", str);
}

int main() {
    FILE *boards_file = fopen("files/boards", "r");
    char c[BOARD_SIZE + 1];
    int count = 0;
    int sub_board_count = 0;
    boards = malloc(sizeof(char**) * BOARDS);
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARDS; i++) {
        boards[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * BOARD_SIZE);
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
            boards[i][j] = malloc(BOARD_SIZE + 1);
        }
    }

    printf("loading...\n");
    printf("here\n");
    while (fread(&c, 1, BOARD_SIZE, boards_file)) {
        printf("here\n");
        strcat(boards[count][sub_board_count], c);
        printf("here\n");
        printf("%s -> %s (%i, %i)\n", c, boards[count][sub_board_count], count, sub_board_count);

        fseek(boards_file, 1, SEEK_CUR);
        sub_board_count++;
        if (sub_board_count == 5) {
            // We reached the end of the board!
            count++;
            sub_board_count = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("done loading, printing...\n-----\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARDS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%s\n", boards[i][j]);
        }
        printf("-----\n");
    }
    fclose(boards_file);
    printf("done loading boards, loading words...\n");

    FILE *words_file = fopen("files/words", "r");
    char c2[BOARD_SIZE + 1];
    printf("here\n");
    while (fread(&c2, 1, BOARD_SIZE, words_file)) {
        printf("here\n");
        add(c2);
    }

    printf("program done, freeing...\n");
    // don't forget to close and free everthing!
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARDS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
            free(boards[i][j]);
        }
        free(boards[i]);
    }
    free(boards);
}
```

When compiled with gcc (full command: `gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow    wordbord-solver.c  -lcrypt -lm -lgmp -o wordbord-solver` (I know I don't need those links but they're useful for other programs, ie make <name>), a segfault occurs on line 95, the second while loop.

Thank you in advance for your time. Apologies if I am being stupid and missing something obvious, but some google digging showed that lines like `char c[BOARD_SIZE + 1]` worked as well as some heap stuff (e.g. `char *c = malloc(BOARD_SIZE + 1); memset(c, 0, BOARD_SIZE + 1);`)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to print the string `c2` but you haven't null-terminated it (afaik). In fact, you are reading BOARDSIZE bytes, which sounds like a board with no null-termination.  Maybe you meant to read BOARDSIZE+1 bytes because you did write a null-terminator originally? (In this case you will need to add 1 to your mallocs.

Comment: "[A]n array of 2d arrays of chars" is **not** a data structure described by `char ***`.  Arrays and pointers are totally different things.

Comment: Thank you! This makes so much more sense. @JohnBollinger, do you have any propositions on how I can more clearly define this data structure?

Comment: @mmixLinus Aren't I already doing that? Line 61; `malloc(BOARD_SIZE + 1);`

Comment: @ZWORX52, since the dimensions are compile-time constants, why not just declare `boards` as a *bona fide* multidimensional array?  `char boards[BOARDS][BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE + 1];`

Comment: That would allow you to completely do away with all the dynamic allocation for that object, yet still access its elements via the same syntax.  This assumes, however, that an array of arrays (of arrays) is really what you want in the first place -- I haven't analyzed your code thoroughly enough to be sure about that.

Comment: Yes, I do want that (An array of 2d boards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issues

Here are some issues that might be causing your segmentation fault:

1. Both the buffer `c` and `c2` are declared on the stack, and not null-terminated. You're unsafely assuming they are null-terminated. This can easily be a source of a segfault when you try to `printf` these buffers (`printf` always searches for the null character as an indication of the end of the buffer)
2. You are using `strcat` in the same way on a non-nulled buffer that you allocate for your 2D boards (`strcat(boards[count][sub_board_count], c);`). You `malloc`'d these buffers but that memory isn't guaranteed to be zero. `strcat` also looks for a null character to indicate where to begin concatenating.
3. You indefinitely read in boards from the file `boards_file`, and never check to see if you have capacity. You've fixed your board count at `730` (`#define BOARDS 730`). If the file contains more, you'll also get a segmentation fault because you don't perform a bounds check.

#### Fixes

- Always zero your stack buffers. You can do this with: `char c[N] = {0}; // Zeroes the entire buffer`.
- Always zero your allocated memory, if you'll be storing strings in them and using C string functions. So either use `memset` or `calloc` to allocate them zeroed.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't need calloc for my pointer allocations - that's a bad idea, right?

Comment: @ZWORX52 You only need to zero the memory holding the string. So `boards[i][j] = malloc(BOARD_SIZE + 1);`. There is a use case for zeroing the array's of pointers too, but I won't over-explain.

Comment: I modified my code, and line 33 (`c2[BOARD_SIZE + 1] = { 0 };` now), and the fread right after is still segfaulting. I don't understand, as I allocated enough space in the buffer `c2` (enough for the chars I intend to read + the \0).

Comment: @ZWORX52 Do you have the files available for me to test?

Comment: Yes! I'll send them over as soon as I can. I did just realize the point of all my worries about fread crashing - I don't actually have the words file! *facepalm* Do you still need them?

Comment: If the program now works, then no. If there remain segmentation fault issues, then yes. @ZWORX52

Comment: Sorry for all of your trouble. It works.  I feel so bad that I missed this!